# Running MySQL from command line

Tags: mysql

I have very recently installed MySQL using Zend Server in an effort to learn PHP and MySQL.

Installation went perfectly, however I installed it in my E: Drive as opposed to installing it in C drive. To launch it from the command line I am given to understand one must type, the following.

```
"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld" -u root
```

or some variant. In my case, `mysqld` is in `E:\Zend\MySQL55\bin`.

However when I type in `E:\Zend\MySQL55\bin\mysqld`, the command line freezes and I can no longer enter anything. If I simply open the .exe file from the folder it's in, a command prompt window opens up and in the same sense freezes and I can't access it.

Is there another way to open it or is what I'm doing close but slightly wrong?

Comment: mysqld is the server, it has no -u option, mysql.exe is the command line client, it has a -u option and needs a running server process

Comment: Thank you. Just figured that out. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For starting the server,

```
 C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysqld --console
```

To login, open a new command prompt window,

```
 C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysql -u root
```

Then it will ask for password and you can enter

Comment: I just like to point this out. After `mysqld` has been executed, the `console window` wouldn't be usable at all because it is waiting for the server(`mysqld`) to stop and all you need to do is close it or you could just minimize it if want to stop the mysql server after, you just need to press `ctrl+break` on console window where you executed the `mysqld` to stop the operation.

Answer (score 2):

In fact, **mysqld is the server**.
If you want to launch the client you have to call **mysql**

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.0\bin\mysql -u root
```